# How to loop through object in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am getting `TypeError: field[i] is undefined` from this:

```
function ObserverFetch() {

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "Observer.aspx/ObserverFetch",
                   data: JSON.stringify({ id: "" }),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: true,
                   success: function (data, status) {

                       $.each(data, function (i, field) {

                           alert(field[i].BidderName);
                           //$('#dvBids').text(field);
                           //$("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + field.SrNo + "</td><td>" + field.BidderName + "</td><td>" + field.BidAmt + "</td></tr>");
                       });                     
                   },
                   failure: function (data) {
                       alert(data.d);
                   },
                   error: function (data) {
                       alert(data.d);
                   }
               });
       }
```

This is what I get in `field`

```
[{"SrNo":4,"BidderName":"faisal","BidAmt":6000000.0000,"BidDate":"\/Date(1430199508063)\/"},{"SrNo":3,"BidderName":"arbaaz jalil","BidAmt":5000010.0000,"BidDate":"\/Date(1430199494083)\/"},{"SrNo":2,"BidderName":"arbaaz","BidAmt":500000.0000,"BidDate":"\/Date(1430199483530)\/"},{"SrNo":1,"BidderName":"shekhar1","BidAmt":5000.0000,"BidDate":"\/Date(1430199394957)\/"}]
```

**$('#dvBids').text(JSON.stringify(data)); gives me :**

```
{"d":"[{\"SrNo\":4,\"BidderName\":\"faisal\",\"BidAmt\":6000000.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199508063)\\/\"},{\"SrNo\":3,\"BidderName\":\"arbaaz jalil\",\"BidAmt\":5000010.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199494083)\\/\"},{\"SrNo\":2,\"BidderName\":\"arbaaz\",\"BidAmt\":500000.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199483530)\\/\"},{\"SrNo\":1,\"BidderName\":\"shekhar1\",\"BidAmt\":5000.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199394957)\\/\"}]"}
```

**$.each(data.d , function (i, field) { gives me :**

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bizarrely, the response from your server is a JSON object with a single property, `d`, which is a **string** containing the JSON for an array. If it's your server method generating that response, you probably want to adjust it so that `data.d` is an array, not a string.

To get those results and loop through them, you'll need to parse it, and then use `field` directly rather than via `i`:

```
var fields = JSON.parse(data.d);
$.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    alert(field.BidderName);
});
```

or of course:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data.d), function(i, field) {
    alert(field.BidderName);
});
```

---

Side note: As the parsed version of `data.d` is an array, on any modern browser you can use `Array#forEach` rather than `$.each`, which has a slightly less-confusing argument list for the callback. (`Array#forEach` can be easily polyfilled on IE8 and earlier.)

```
JSON.parse(data.d).forEach(function(field) {
    alert(field.BidderName);
});
```

---

**Live Example** of both:

```js
var data = {
    "d": "[{\"SrNo\":4,\"BidderName\":\"faisal\",\"BidAmt\":6000000.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199508063)\\/\"},{\"SrNo\":3,\"BidderName\":\"arbaaz jalil\",\"BidAmt\":5000010.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199494083)\\/\"},{\"SrNo\":2,\"BidderName\":\"arbaaz\",\"BidAmt\":500000.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199483530)\\/\"},{\"SrNo\":1,\"BidderName\":\"shekhar1\",\"BidAmt\":5000.0000,\"BidDate\":\"\\/Date(1430199394957)\\/\"}]"
};

snippet.log("Using $.each:");
$.each(JSON.parse(data.d), function(i, field) {
  snippet.log(field.BidderName);
});

snippet.log("----");
snippet.log("Using forEach");
JSON.parse(data.d).forEach(function(field) {
  snippet.log(field.BidderName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks it your solution worked. I have added the serverside code in my question. I am pretty noob when it comes to Jquery/ajax requests.

Comment: @Arbaaz: Glad this helped. I'd remove the server-side code from the question and post a *new* question saying "How can I make this code return an array for `data.d` rather than a string?" (including the JSON it currently returns). Best,

Comment: going to do exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in `var fiel` you already have a each element of the array. The solutiobn is:

```
$.each( obj, function (i, field) {
  alert(field.BidderName );
});
```